# Formula linking size of centralizer and number of conjugacy classes for a finite group $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

My course says it's easily explained that $\sum_{\substack{g\in G}} |C_G(g)|=m\times|G|$ where $m$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

I don't think I see it that easily... Can you tell me about it?

I thought about using $|C_G(g)|\times|C(g)|=|G|$ or maybe trying to consider only one element of each conjugacy classes but I don't see it. I'm probably missing something quite obvious...

Thank you!

Comment: Use Burnside's lemma.

Comment: Hum... I'm not sure I see it... I see it's useful but not exactly how, can you hint me?

Comment: I do, I do, considering the conjugacy actions from G on itself, the number of orbits is the number of conjugacy classes and $fix(g)=C_G(g)$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The conjugacy class of each $g \in G$ contributes $|C_G(g)| \cdot |C(g)| = |G|$ to the sum.

Answer (score 1):

it is a special form of Burnside's lemma but we can do it by hand,

It is enough to show that the sum is equal to $|G|$ on one conjugacy class then reslt follows.

Let $O$ be one of the conjugacy class,

$$\sum_{x\in O} |C_G(x)|=\sum_{x\in O}\dfrac{|G|}{|O|}=|G|\sum_{x\in O}\dfrac{1}{|O|}=|G|$$

**Note:** notice that on one conjugacy class, $|C_G(x)|$ has fixed order and by orbit stabilizer therem $$|C_G(x)|=\dfrac{|G|}{|O|}$$